# Selecting one line from a large variable PHP

Tags: php, variables, explode

Currently I have two files containing PHP.

One file runs the main script, A.php. The second file, B.php contains a variable $lines.

A.php:

```
include("b.php");
$p = explode("\n", $lines);
$p = $p[rand(0, count($p)-1)];
$p = explode(":", $p);
```

B.php:

```
$lines= "data1:data2
data1:data2
data1:data2
data1:data2"; //(the actual variable contains 3,000 lines)
```

A.php is including B.php, exploding the variable and retrieving a random line to use. Now that B.php contains 3,000 lines, it has become 83kb, and I fear that it is slowing down A.php.

Is there a more efficient way around this?

Comment: Use a database to store data, that will be much more efficient.

Comment: You could start by storing the result of `explode()`. Is b.php changed by another process?

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply - how much more efficient would it be to add these into a database and using a MYSQL command to select a random line?

Answer (score 0):

With this much data it would be best to use a database imo, but you can just read a specific line using the [SplFileObject](http://php.net/splfileobject), and use an actual datafile instead of a php script (just put the data into a regular text file).

```
$rndNum = 530; //Generate your random line number.
$file = new SplFileObject('b.txt');
$file->seek($rndNum); //put file cursor at line $rndNum+1
echo $file->current();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - this worked the best for my code.
The MySQL method put too much strain on my DB server.